# In React app, render() fails because document.getElementById('root') returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**Update 2**: It **was** a problem with my setup. I upgraded `react-scripts` using `yarn upgrade react-scripts` to version 1.0.2 (was 0.9.5), and now it actually works again.

**Update**: I'm starting to think it's a problem with my node.js setup. 
Even older commits, which I'm sure worked before, no longer work. I didn't get anywhere with `git bisect` (although I'm glad I learned about it).

---

I'm fairly sure I'm not the only one with this problem, because I have seen this question asked more than once. However, none of the answers provided so far have helped me solve it.

I have a React app, that fails in `render()` (in `index.js`):

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
            routes={config.router.routes}
            history={browserHistory}
        />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The last line in the function returns `null`. In the Chrome developer console, this become clear (I added a `console.log` to show that the result is `null`):

[image: root element not found]

It's fairly obvious that particular error occurs because `render()` gets `null` as the second parameter.

However, for the life of me I can't find out why it returns `null`. I was happily coding away until at some point last night when it stopped working. My `public/index.html` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
    window.settings = {
        "apiUrl": "https://api.goes.here",
        "imgUrl": "https://api.goes.here"
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I've clear the actual api values.)

I don't see anything wrong with this too. Now, given that the problem occurred out of the blue, I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious. For completeness, here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "compression": "^1.5.2",
    "firebase": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "linc-profile-generic-react-redux-routerv3": "^3.4.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "query-string": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-helmet": "^5.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
    "react-spinkit": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.7.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this. I've ran out of ideas.

Thanks! 
Sander

Comment: at what point in your HTML do you load your script? if your `render` runs before the DOM has been constructed, then your root element won't exist yet.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. How do I find out? Because what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: If it suddenly stopped working, then it might be useful to track down the exact change that caused it. If you're using Git then the bisect command would be useful for that.

Comment: Can you inspect the html with chrome dev tools and see where it inject script tags with the bundle js file? it should be inside body and below the root div tag

Comment: Something new to learn. Heard about `git bisect`, but haven't used it yet. Thanks. :)

Comment: The HTML you're posting doesn't contain the `script` tag that loads your index.js - that's where you need to look to see if the DOM is loaded first @Sandyman

If you're using a templating system, it might be in there?

Comment: It seems the react-scripts do that for me. It's working now. I haven't changed the index.html code at all, but the script section shows up in the source when I view Page Source in Chrome. React magic??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. I upgraded the `react-tools` from 0.9.5 to 1.0.2 and now everything works like a charm again. I'm thinking maybe at some point I'd already upgraded to this version, but failed to commit it.

A big thank you to everyone who responded to this question! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ReactDOM.render method directly;

Example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
            routes={config.router.routes}
            history={browserHistory}
        />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am sorry if you are already doing this, by it's not entirely clear whether you are trying to execute the render method from within a class component or not.

Comment: I pasted my entire `index.js` in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/nauz4XAB

In short:
`import { render} from 'react-dom'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sandyman I ran your index.js sans the custom authentication and config options and it seems to work just fine. Finds root and renders a div with 'Hello World!' inside.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exact `index.js` you used? Even with your feedback, I can't get it to work. :(

Comment: Hey, here's a pastebin of what worked for me: https://pastebin.com/cEeaW4q8 . Could some other component be blocking the DOM virtualization?

Comment: Yeah probably. I'm a bit of a newby to React, though, so I'm not sure where to look. I think I may give it a rest for the day. Thanks so far!